# Are main command line args stored in stack memory or heap memory?

Tags: java, memory, jvm, stack, heap-memory

This may be a dumb question...

Looking at how are the JVM stack memory and heap memory are usually drawn at the university, they usually show the call stack with the called methods, the variables defined in them and the arguments (stack memory) and any allocated objects (heap memory).

Taking a simple hello world example:

```java
public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

They always omit the static main arguments (`String[] args`) in the drawing. Is there a special rule or place where the args are stored that is different from normal stack memory arguments?

Without being able to find a result in Google I have to suppose that without a special rule/exception, i should have in stack a "args" variable pointing to a heap-allocated array containing the command line arguments, am I wrong?

Comment: Arrays are objects. So heap it is.

Comment: thanks @Turing85, so there's no weird storing place or exception for them?
Then, is it just omitted from drawing them for clarity?

Comment: I don’t think there is a rule. Any JVM could sensibly choose one or the other. I trust that @Turing85 is correct that the current Oracle JVM version uses the heap, but there’s nothing that I can see that would keep the next version from using the stack instead if the developers choose so.

Comment: Okay, I have to correct myself. The JLS is pretty shallow as to where objects are stored. The [JVMS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.3), on the other hand, is pretty verbose: "*he heap is the run-time data area from which **memory for all class instances and arrays** is allocated.*"

Comment: Arguments are almost the same as local variables, just initialized outside the method. Each method call gets a *Frame* on the stack, that, among others, contains the local variables which includes the parameters. Sure the referenced instances are on the heap. where all instances are. JVM Specification: [2.6. Frames](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se12/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6)

Comment: And one more twist: If the compiler can determine that `args` is never used (is in your program and very many other programs), it can opt not to allocate the array at all. I got no idea whether this happens in practice or not, but it would work.

Comment: @OleV.V. not for the `main` method…

Answer (score 1):

The command-line arguments are stored in a `String`-array. [All arrays are stored on the heap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.3). Thus, the command-line arguments are stored on the heap.

I assume that your supervisors - as you suggested in your comment - omit them for clarity.